Stop debian from permitting all remaining space being used and bricking
I have Debian 12 Bookworm installed, everything is installed on the same partition as this is a prebuilt system I am working with, I am trying to put a hard limit on the space that can be used on my main drive sda1 and bricking the system. I have attempted to set it using tune2fs with the following command
/sbin/tune2fs -m5 /dev/sda1

but when I created a placeholder file using dd command that would be larger than the space of the drive. I rebooted the system and it bricked.
How can I properly reserve space to ensure that the total available space cannot be completely used up bricking the system?

Reserved space is reserved for root, so only root can fill it. The idea is to run as little as possible as root, so that there's always space left for root to login.
Another fix for you is to move things to other partitions, e.g. have /var and /usr as separate partitions, to ensure that the system can boot. Apart from that there's not a whole lot you can do; full disk is full disk, and it doesn't matter to the process attempting to write why the write is blocked - it will fail either way.


How can I properly reserve space to ensure that the total available space cannot be completely used up bricking the system?

Setting such a limit system-wide would literally make the reserved space no longer available. Meaning, you'd get the same result as soon as you hit the custom limit – the system wouldn't be able to use the rest of "available" space for the same reason that you aren't able to use it – so all it would achieve is make the system run out of available space faster (because now there's less of it).
(Though it doesn't really brick the system as such, because you're still able to recover it without needing specialist tools; at worst you have to boot in rescue mode and fix it from there. Bricking implies getting the device to a state such that there's nothing more you can do except throw it out a window.)
What you'd need to do is set specific limits based on who's using the space, and this could be done e.g. by user or by group using the "quota" mechanism – assuming the filesystem supports it, you can limit the 'users' group to 100G usable, for example.
But this still won't help, because the entity that deliberately filled up space using 'dd' was actually the same entity that would've needed that space during system boot. Quotas are useless if you try to fill the disk as root, because it's the same user as the services which need the disk space – essentially, root is the OS. (Your tune4fs-set limit already reserves that 5% for root, too, and the fact that it didn't work means that most other mechanisms aren't going to work either.)
Though you could try to achieve this using "project quotas", with a PAM module that sets a generic non-zero project ID for all users upon login (whereas services would be unaffected), as long as you carefully consider which PAM services should set the project ID (and whether root should have it separate from normal users, so that they could still log in when the system needs to be cleaned up).
Quotas might help if you try to guard the disk from being filled up by normal users. But a user whose disk usage has reached the limits still won't be able to log in through GUI, for example, because their GUI is running under the same account and therefore shares the same quota.

Is there a way to reserve a space for the user accounts to keep them from accidentally overwriting the space and keep being able to login?

No, for reasons I've already explained.
